# Unexpected rounding of double value at save method in php

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working with cakephp 3.4 and I've installed the friendsofcake/crud plugin, what i want is save double values in the format of two digits before the decimal point and eight digits after the decimal point, the problem is the saved value is only 2 digits before the decimal point and six digits after the decimal point>

Comment: I think you need to read about [php sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [printf precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Precision_field).

Comment: I have created a function that insert the same data that the plugin do, and it's working fine.
the question is how to make validation on the saveMethod to force it to take 8 digits after the decimal point , Note the saveMethod is from the firendsofcake/crud plugin

Comment: What DBMS do you use?